# Display opportunities associated with an OpportunityLineItem

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity-lineitem

I'm trying to display opportunities associated with an `OpportunityLineItem` on a Visualforce page on the `OpportunityLineItem` object

I have a problem in the select I do not know how to retrieve the `OpportunityLineItem` name in this request I have hard code the `OpportunityLineItem` name

```
public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOpp() {
    return [SELECT TotalPrice, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.StageName, 
                   Opportunity.Account.Name, Opportunity.id, Product2.Name 
            FROM OpportunityLineItem  
            WHERE Product2.Name='GenWatt Diesel 10kW'
    ];
}
```

[image: Opportunity related to productLineItem]

Comment: Hi Anirbas, welcome to SFSE. Could you [edit] your question to be a little clearer about what you're trying to do and on which object? If your page is shown on the `OpportunityLineItem` page, it's not clear why you're trying to select based on the associated Product name. And remember, Opportunities have many Line Items, but Line Items have only one Opportunity.

Comment: hi david thank you for your reactivity
my client wants a visualforce page on the productLineItem object that displays the opportunities associated with the product that is on the productLineItem

Comment: There is no such thing as a ProductLineItem, at least in vanilla Sales Cloud. It'll be much easier to help you if you could reference the ERD that PartOfTheOhana posted below and be careful about which objects you're referring to. I think what you want is "All Opportunities associated with the same Product as this OpportunityLineItem". Is that correct? If so, please [edit] your question.

Comment: exactly David this is what i want

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your query using a field value from the record whose page you're displaying upon.

A Visualforce page surfaced on the record page for some object must use the standard controller and a controller extension. Every controller extension's constructor receives a reference to the standard controller:

```
public MyControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController c) {
```

It is typical to save a reference to this standard controller in an instance variable such as `controller`. You may then call the standard controller directly to obtain access to field values, or simply obtain the Record Id and perform your own query. Here's one example:

```
SELECT ... fields ...
FROM OpportunityLineItem
WHERE Product2Id = :controller.getRecord().Product2Id
```

If `Product2Id` is not being automatically queried by the standard controller due to a dependency expressed in the Visualforce page, you must call `addFields()` on the standard controller in your constructor to ensure it is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Salesforce ERD. Note the[OpportunityLineItem] documentation for available [fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm#!)

For your question, I'm not really clear on what you're asking.  if you're saying the issue is how to get the opp line item name, try this

```
public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOpp() {
   return [SELECT TotalPrice, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.StageName, 
               Opportunity.Account.Name, Opportunity.id, Product2.Name , Name
        FROM OpportunityLineItem  
        WHERE Product2.Name='GenWatt Diesel 10kW' 
  ];
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm

[image]

Comment: it works for the product 'GenWatt Diesel 10kW'  but not for  all products

Comment: the filter is limiting your query to only return line items where  the name of the product ='GenWatt Diesel 10kW'.... if you want it remove that restriction remove the where clause.

Comment: in this case I will display all the opportunities having a product but I need the opportunities associated with the productLineItem on which is my visualforce page

Comment: what i want is "All Opportunities associated with the same Product as this OpportunityLineItem"